# Test Automation of data pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, apache-nifi, powerbi-desktop

I have been asked to do test automation of below data pipeline. can somebody suggest/direct me how i can achieve end to end automation testing of this pipeline.

*I'm looking for framework, tools which i can use for entire test automation.*

**Oracle DW -> Apache Nifi -> AWS S3 (landing area) -> [Using AWS Lambda step function & cloud watch] -> To store data into AWS Redshift -> Power BI**

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a Python client for Apache NiFi in order to automate deployment and testing with it, so this should help you for the initial stages of your pipeline
https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi